# Jquery Counting child in nested list, Search and Expand Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop expand collapse, search in nested list and count of child lists but I don't know how to implement all these.

HTML

```
<div class="searchSection">
  <form action="#" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search here...">
  </form>
  <ul id="orgCat">
    <li parent-id="" li-id="1">
      <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>India</div>
      <ul>
        <li parent-id="1" li-id="2">
          <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>Ap</div>
          <ul>
            <li parent-id="2" li-id="7">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>vag</div>
            </li>
            <li parent-id="2" li-id="8">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>tirupati</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li parent-id="1" li-id="3">
          <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>TN</div>
          <ul>
            <li parent-id="3" li-id="9">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>chena</div>
            </li>
            <li parent-id="3" li-id="10">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>India1</div>
            </li>
            <li parent-id="3" li-id="11">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>India2</div>
            </li>
            <li parent-id="3" li-id="12">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>India3</div>
            </li>
            <li parent-id="3" li-id="13">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>India4</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li parent-id="1" li-id="4">
          <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>TS</div>
          <ul>
            <li parent-id="4" li-id="5">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>Hyd</div>
            </li>
            <li parent-id="4" li-id="6">
              <div class="expandBtn"><span id="count"></span>warangal</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on the 'div' tag it should be expand or collapse. Count of children should be appear in 'span' tag. When I search an element, it should appear from it's root directory. I hope you guys understand.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/2/)

Jquery

```
// counting leafs
$('.searchSection').each(function(){
    $('#count').text($('ul').children().length);
})
```

above jquery displaying total 'li' elements but i need to display number of li elements in each ul.

I don't know how to implement Collapse and Expand functionality. I am new to Jquery.

Comment: check my updated question or please check out this. https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/1/

Comment: A ***simple addition*** of the jQuery library and some quotes around `input`... [Changes your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/qn6ah1k2/) so much! FROM THAT, Please edit your question.

Comment: Search Done, Thank you. What about Counting

Comment: Nelson... Who are you talking to? Can you clarify your question, which I already voted to close as *«a simple typo.»* (Missing quotes on the event handler selector)?

Comment: I want three functionalities 1. Search, 2. Collapse Expand, 3. Number of children in each ul

Comment: wtf... What is that «I want»? It should be can you explain why... Or how to...

Comment: do you want all elements counted, or just the end leaf count for each branch?

Comment: Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/2/

Comment: end leaf of each branch

Comment: how to expand only selected list elements in this source code. jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should give you the expand and colapse and count of all list items under a parent.

```
//Search query    
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var searchTerms = $(this).val();

  $('li').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 || $li.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.toLowerCase()) > 0;

    $li.toggle(hasMatch);
    if ($li.is(":hidden")) {
      $li.closest("ul").show();
    }

  });
});

var $expandBtns = $(".expandBtn");

$expandBtns.each(function() {
  var $span = $(this).find("span#count");
  var $subList = $(this).siblings("ul").find("li")

  $span.text($subList.length)
});

$expandBtns.on("click", function() {
  var $subList = $(this).siblings("ul");

  if ($subList.is(":visible")) {
    $subList.hide();
  } else {
    $subList.show();
  }
})
```

Comment: It's working thank you so much. I have one more issue please check out this link https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/3/ . In this when i search a particular name it's not appearing when list is collapsed.

Comment: resolve in this Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/5/ . issue 1. searched item is not displaying When it is collapsed. issue 2. when the page loads collapse all childs

Comment: Issue 2 resolved, can any one help me to resolve issue 1 from my above comments

Comment: you did some changes is in your previous answer. check on peer review. with your 1st answer all functionalities are worked well but with the latest answer functionalities are not worked.

Comment: still I am facing the problem with Search "searched item is not displaying When it is collapsed".

Comment: @nelsonfeel the link to your fiddle doesn't show my code changes in it. I'm not sure how to update your fiddle. Can you copy paste my answer into your fiddle to see if it will work?

Comment: @nelsonfeel Can you try this fiddle out? https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/13/

Comment: done. One more issue. In my list 'TS' has sub-list. If I searched for TS it's showing but When I am click on TS sub-list is not expanding. https://jsfiddle.net/vt0tw50e/17/

Comment: @nelsonfeel that is because the filter function hides everything that doesn't match the search term including children. You will have to rewrite it to toggle all the children back on some how. I'm not sure how to do that off the top of my head.